# How to parse this string by strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, strptime

Somtetimes I see date strings like this `"2015-04-09T10:59:22Z"`.
What are "T" and "Z" chars here? How to parse this string by python's `time.strptime`?

Comment: The `'Z'` is for the [`UTC` zone in ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC). `'T'` comes from the [combined date and time representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations),

Answer (score 1):

```
astr = "2015-04-09T10:59:22Z"
time.strptime(astr, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
## returns time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=10, tm_min=59, tm_sec=22, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=99, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
print date_parse("2015-04-09T10:59:22Z")
```

it doesnt use strptime ... but you dont need to worry about the date format pretty much ever

(oh yeah you may need `pip install python-dateutil` ) :P

Comment: aaaawesome; I didn't know that one.

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` has excellent documentation in its `man` [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) (`man strptime`) and [on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.strftime).

You'll have to tell **us** what the extra characters mean, because we don't know where the string comes from. However, assuming `T` and `Z` don't mean anything special:

```
time.strptime(your_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
```

should do the trick.

EDIT: The `Z` is a timezone abbreviation; hence the trailing `%Z`.

EDIT2: ah if python's `strptime` just understood `%Z`. You'll have to ignore it as constant (means UTC, if I'm not totally mistaken)

```
time.strptime(your_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

EDIT3: **Z**ulu time, as I've learned.

Comment: unfortunately I think the Z means UTC (or something ... but just ignoring it is probably fine tbh)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right... `strftime(3)` had something about that, but I can't find it in the haste.

Comment: unfortunately iirc python strptime doesnt understand the `Z` so it likely wont match :/

Comment: @JoranBeasley aaah why can't reality align with my expectation?

Comment: (hehe hence my comment why you can probably just ignore it (or do something like `your_date.replace("Z","UTC")` see:http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)

Comment: lol so close ... its actually zulutime its used in avaiation (and most gps type sensors ... although it has a zero hour offset from UTC :P)

Comment: Reality can go home and have a shot of whiskey. I'll have a round of sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work and are correct, and yes, "Z" is for Zulu, the old way of referring to UTC.

The problem parsing with the standard library the string, even replacing the `Z` with `UTC` still renders a time zone *naive* datetime object.  This is a work around I use to create a time zone *aware* datetime  object

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
time_string = '1582-10-04T12:34:56.789Z'
timeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
datetime.strptime(time_string, timeformat).replace(tzinfo=(timezone(timedelta(0))))
# or in your case
time_string = '2015-04-09T10:59:22Z'
timeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'  # No microseconds
datetime.strptime(time_string, timeformat).replace(tzinfo=(timezone(timedelta(0))))
```